# Logo and nav are not centered in header

Tags: html, css

I have created a codepen showing [this problem here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJppJY?editors=1100)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #F4F2E9;
}

header {
  background-color: #A3C5C3;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 194px;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333D51;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding: 0 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar li a:hover:not(.active) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar li.active a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

section {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.categories {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.categories h2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.categories li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 21px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333D51;
}

.category-button {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.category-button:hover {
  background-color: #D2AC2B;
}

.category-button-initial {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #D2AC2B;
}

.products {
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
}

.products h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.products ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.products li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #dcdbdb;
  min-height: 133px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 15px;
}

.products img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 133px;
  width: 200px;
}

.products div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 240px;
  /* changed 2-3*/
  float: left;
  /* changed*/
}

.product-title {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.product-price {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

footer {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #A3C5C3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./coderthreads.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./coderthreads.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/0b526260fb.png" alt="Coder Threads Logo">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class='navbar'>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class='active'>
        <a href='#'>Shop</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Store Locator</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section>
  <div class='categories'>
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#shirts' class='category-button category-button-initial'>Shirts</a></li>
      <li><a href='#pants' class='category-button'>Pants</a></li>
      <li><a href='#accessories' class='category-button'>Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='shirts' class='products'>
    <h2>Shirts</h2>
    <ul>
      <li id="prod1">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/13de3c2e5e.png" alt="Women's Classic T-Shirt">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Women's Classic T-Shirt</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
          <span class="product-price">$10.00</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="prod2">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/141af47f49.png" alt="Men's Leather Jacket">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Men's Leather Jacket</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed lectus sagittis est congue, eu adipiscing amet libero. Luctus enim ante massa felis amet ac, omnis integer, aliquam viverra amet ornare sed, sed voluptate placerat enim tellus elit.</span>
          <span class="product-price">$55.00</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="prod3">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/1421c7aae2.png" alt="Women's Gray Hooded Sweatshirt">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Women's Gray Hooded Sweatshirt</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sitipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
          <span class="product-price">$35.00</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="prod4">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/14240b9f18.png" alt="Men's Athletic Compression Top">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Men's Athletic Compression Top</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
          <span class="product-price">$45.00</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='pants' class='products'>
    <h2>Pants</h2>
    <ul>
      <li id="prod5">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/14f6c3d696.png" alt="Men's Olive Chinos">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Men's Olive Chinos</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
          <span class="product-price">$45.00</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="prod6">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/210b60d480.png" alt="Women's Distressed Jeans">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Women's Distressed Jeans</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed lectus sagittis est congue, eu adipiscing amet libero. Luctus enim ante massa felis amet ac, omnis integer, aliquam viverra amet ornare sed, sed voluptate placerat enim tellus elit.</span>
          <span class="product-price">$50.00</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="prod7">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/14f86a5ef4.png" alt="Women's Skinny Mid Tone Jeans">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Women's Skinny Mid Tone Jeans</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
          <span class="product-price">$40.00</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='accessories' class='products'>
    <h2>Accessories</h2>
    <ul>
      <li id="prod8">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/1508f24253.png" alt="Leather Book Bag">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Leather Book Bag</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
          <span class="product-price">$55.00</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="prod9">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/1508dc9fb3.png" alt="Laptop Bag">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Laptop Bag</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
          <span class="product-price">$40.00</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="prod10">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/1508d3b63e.png" alt="Five Panel Hat">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Five Panel Hat</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed lectus sagittis est congue, eu adipiscing amet libero. Luctus enim ante massa felis amet ac, omnis integer, aliquam viverra amet ornare sed, sed voluptate placerat enim tellus elit.</span>
          <span class="product-price">$30.00</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="prod11">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/1508c85d59.png" alt="Apple Watch">
        <div>
          <span class="product-title">Apple Watch</span>
          <span class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
          <span class="product-price">$199.99</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<footer>
  ~ don't code without your threads ~
</footer>
```

I am trying to center the navigation with the logo in the blue header using:

```
nav {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333D51;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

As well as replacing `justify-content:center;` with `text-align:center;`

However the navigation is not centering. Any tips on this would be great.

Comment: to me seems correctly centered ..

Comment: If you compare it to the navigation it is not

Comment: @Temple Notice that the text "SHOP" in the navigation is not centred.

Comment: @Temple Have you tried setting a `width` on `.navbar li`? Doing so centres "SHOP" which makes it align properly under the logo.

Comment: Hey @AndrewMorton I did try doing so and it centered it, but it removed all li elements except HOME

Comment: @Temple You will have to work out the correct width to use and probably remove padding/margins elsewhere.

Comment: @Temple If you set the width of `.navbar li` to 160px (or whatever units work for the site) and remove the padding on `.navbar li a` then you will have a reasonable display.

Answer (score 0):

It's your `footer` element messing things.
Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the footer or change the padding to `25px 0px`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly the problem is:

The image is the problem i.e. the logo is not in the center of the image.

So what you need to do is correctly square off the image.

once the png image has the actual logo centered, then i would look at cropping to say 200x200 or what ever but the logo is not in the center of the actual image i.e. nothing to do with styling or html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that the links are all different sizes so they aren't centered. If you add use flexbox and add something like this it should work:

```
.navbar {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.navbar li {
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-basis0;
}
```